# Uwp : Make a resizable image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

uwp beginner, I would like to display an image and make it resizable by the user with drag an drop.

Suggestions and code sample will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by resizable? Like changing size in pixels of the image file? Or like zooming and panning? Also what do you mean by drag&drop?

Comment: Could you please give more details about the behavior you want to achieve? I have the same questions as @Alamakanambra.